# How to use the Log block:column indication to locate SAS macro-programming errors?

Tags: logging, sas

If open code is submitted to SAS, information (founded on the SAS log) like "NOTE: Division by zero detected at line 3 column 24" is useful because its interpretation is easy. But the same is not true when macro code is concerned.
As Paul D. Sherman explains in a useful paper (https://www.lexjansen.com/wuss/2006/data_presentation_and_business_intelligence/DPR-Sherman.pdf), in the macro-context, the open code "line:column" notation should be interpreted as "block:character".
While deserving some update, including mentioning the new (SAS 9.3) option RESETLINE (very useful for open code), this paper illustrates how SAS divides the macro code into blocks (and, moreover, takes into account the iteration number in case of nested macros with %DO loops).
Because each data step, in a macro, accounts for a block (of lines) the location, within that block,  of the character where SAS has detected a problem should be done, if my understanding is correct, according to the following rules: count every character since the initial DATA statement, for every line, including blank lines, spaces and, maybe (I'm not sure), one additional character after each semi-colon.
I successfully applied these rules to several short macros.
When a data step, in a macro, only includes some short statements, it is not too long to locate the problem.
But - and it is my question - how to proceed when the data step includes a lot of statements, especially long ones?
Is there a trick allowing the user to quickly locate the Nth character within a log block?

Any help welcome, including links toward detailed explanations about the way SAS delimits blocks in case of macro instructions (ie not data step blocks).

Comment: Add `OPTIONS MPRINT;` before your macro code to get a better log that makes it very easy to debug. In SAS Studio/EG the errors are flagged and you can jump to any error blocks automatically, you don't need to manually search the log.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. When debugging my SAS macros I already use MPRINT (and MLOGIC and SYMBOLGEN as well) but these options don't help  for the specific problem I described above. Moreover, the fixed costs associated to learn how to use SAS Studio/Enterprise Guide are too high as compared to the expected benefits provided by the easier-to-read log they offer. Anyway, I should probably interpret the absence of solution suggested by StackOverFlow experts to my question, as revealing the non-existence of any trick allowing the user to quickly locate the Nth character within a log block.

Comment: SO doesn't have many SAS programmers, try posting on communities.sas.com where the SAS developers or staff will help answer your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this useful suggestion.